# Pattern match over non-constructor functions

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, language-features

One of the most powerful ways pattern matching and lazy evaluation can come together is to bypass expensive computation. However I am still shocked that Haskell only permits the pattern matching of constructors, which is barely pattern matching at all!

Is there some way to impliment the following functionality in Haskell:

```hs
exp :: Double -> Double
exp 0 = 1
exp (log a) = a
--...

log :: Double -> Double
log 1 = 0
log (exp a) = a
--...
```

The original problem I found this useful in was writing an associativity preference / rule in a Monoid class:

```hs
class Monoid m where
  iden :: m
  (+) m -> m -> m

  (+) iden a = a
  (+) a iden = a

  --Line with issue
  (+) ((+) a b) c = (+) a ((+) b c)
```

Comment: Do you know of any languages that do let you do that?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Well, in symbolic languages (Lisps, Mathematica, in a sense Coq, ...) this is not a completely absurd idea.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica apparently, in [Curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry_(programming_language)) one can write `last xs | ys++[e] =:= xs = e where ys,e free`. from Haskell it looks like pattern matching on a `++` call. but in general this should probably appear as laws attached to data types, and maybe to functions, triggering extensive (and probably very expensive) re-write possibilities...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no reason to be shocked about this. How would it be even remotely feasible to pattern match on arbitrary functions? Most functions aren't invertible, and even for those that are it is typically nontrivial to actually compute the inverses.

Of course the compiler could in principle handle trivial examples like replacing literal `exp (log x)` with `x`, but that would be almost completely useless in practice (in the unlikely event somebody were to literally write that, they could as well reduce it right there in the source), and would generally lead to very weird unpredictable behaviour if inlining order changes whether or not the compiler can see that a match applies.

(There is however a thing called [rewrite rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.0.3/docs/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html), which is similar to what you proposed but is seen as only an optimisation tool.)

Even the two lines from the `Monoid` class that don't error don't make sense, but for different reasons. First, when you write

```
  (+) iden a = a
  (+) a iden = a
```

this doesn't do what you seem to think. These are actually two redundant catch-call clauses, equivalent to

```
  (+) x y = y
  (+) x y = x
```

...which is an utterly nonsensical thing to write. What you want to state could in fact be written as

```
  default (+) :: Eq a => a -> a -> a
  x+y
   | x==iden    = y
   | y==iden    = x
   | otherwise  = ...
```

...but this still doesn't accomplish anything useful, because this is never going to be a full definition of `+`. And as soon as a concrete instance even begins to define its own `+` operator, *the complete* default one is going to be ignored.

Moreover, if you were to have these kind of clauses all over your Haskell project it would in practice just mean your performing a lot of unnecessary, redundant extra checks. A law-abiding `Monoid` instance needs to fulfill `mempty <> a ≡ a` *anyway*, no point explicitly special-casing it.

I think what you really want is *tests*. It *would* make sense to specify laws right in a class declaration in a way that they could automatically be checked, but standard Haskell has no syntax for this. Most projects just do it in a separate test suite, using [QuickCheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck) to generate example inputs. I think there's also a tool that allow you to put the test cases right in your source file, but I forgot what it's called.

Comment: "How would it be even remotely feasible to pattern match on arbitrary functions?" -- presumably by having a system of rewrite rules available at runtime. That number that was passed to your function? It's not an eight-byte value representing `72`, it's some variable-size structure that represents the computation `exp 4.276666`. Then I can have my `log` function look at that structure and decide whether to take the log via Taylor expansion or by simply eliminating the outermost `exp` from that structure. I don't think it's absurd to hope for that -- just not what Haskell does.

Comment: @DanielWagner Doesn't that break referential transparency? If `f x` is handled differently from `f (id x)`, I think we have a problem. This might be fixable by requiring the programmer to provide a proof, showing that rewriting rules are confluent. Writing such proofs looks like a daunting task, in general.

Comment: @chi Certainly, it's not referentially transparent. Just like most languages...

Comment: "How would it be even remotely feasible to pattern match on arbitrary functions?", by storing lazy evaluations as compositions. E.g. <<(+), 1>, 1> = 2

Comment: @chi, this would only be a problem if it had side effects or produced a different result. If its purely for optimisations then this is not an issue.

Comment: @Vye What should it do if it matches on `((+) 1 1)`, but you call it with an application of *different* function that also adds two numbers together?

Comment: @DavidYoung Skip the optimisation. This type of pattern matching im on about is only useful for bypassing evaluation and potentially arranging operators into cleanly foldable expressions, in either way, the answer is still determanistic.

Comment: @Vye again, as I wrote, for _optional optimisations_ you can use rewrite rules. But normally, clauses are very much _not_ something that should end up just being skipped, this would be a nightmare for reproducability, test coverage etc..